# Php switch-case with functions doesn't work

Tags: php, switch-statement

Why does the first logic work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Installation Script</title>
</head>
<?php
$step = (isset($_GET['step']) && $_GET['step'] != '') ? $_GET['step'] : '';
switch($step){
  case '1':
  step_1();
  break;
  case '2':
  step_2();
  break;
  case '3':
  step_3();
  break;
  default:
  step_1();
}
?>
<body>

<?php
function step_1(){ 
 some php code for the below form
?>
  form (html code)
<?php 
}

function step_2(){
 some php code for the below form
  ?>
  form (html code)
<?php
}

function step_3(){
 some php code for the below form
?>
form (html code)
<?php
}
?></body>
</html>
```

but the second doesn't?

```
<?php
$result='';
$step = (isset($_GET['step']) && $_GET['step'] != '') ? $_GET['step'] : '';
switch($step){
  case '1':
  step_1();
  break;
  case '2':
  step_2();
  break;
  case '3':
  step_3();
  break;
  default:
  step_1();
}


function step_1(){ 
$result='';
 some php code for the $result form in this function
 $result.='html form';
}

function step_2(){ 
$result='';
 some php code for the $result form in this function
 $result.='html form';
}

function step_3(){ 
$result='';
 some php code for the $result form in this function
 $result.='html form';
}
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf8" />
<title>Install</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<header id="header">
    <h1>Installer</h1>
</header>

<section>
    <?php print $result; ?>
</section>

<footer id="footer">
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's ok,that i shouldn't use an installer like this, i won't, but i only have this code to show you my problem. In my opinion,the second example's structure is more logical than the first one, but it doesn't work. Can you help me? Or where to find some information about this?

Comment: And how is second example supposed to work? Your function does nothing except some string concatenation. Have you ever heard of `return` keyword?

Comment: Where to put the return keyword and how?

Comment: You see, what you're asking is explanation behind a fundamental principle in programming. I am actually amazed you were able to create functions without knowing what `return` is. A `return` construct returns data from a function. Since explaining it to detail and covering it properly would take too much time, I have to suggest to get back to studying programming all together, you really can't develop anything if you can't use functions that return data back.

Comment: This is my first year at school. I just want to understand the difference.

Comment: This is language syntax related and how things work, I can't explain it to you except telling you to google what `return` does and how functions are used. You assumed that `$result` is visible in functions you specified and outside of them - well, it's not.